# (Objective-C / Cocoa) Casted Superclass remains the same

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting, delegates, subclass

I'm working on an subclass of NSURLConnection. I added some properties and functionality. I implemented the NSURLConnectionDelegate and it's methods.

Now I need to pass the NSURLConnection (and it's properties) to my subclasses delegate. I implemented a delegate protocol for this.

Here is an code example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:_didReceiveDataSelector]) {
        [_delegate performSelector:_didReceiveDataSelector withObject:connection];
    }
```

Now I also need to return my subclasses properties. I tried to simply cast the instance:

```
mySubClass *obj = (mySubClass *)connection;
obj.userInfo = self.userInfo;
```

But it turned out (`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([obj class]));`) that the cast returns an object which's class is still NSURLConnection.

Now I wonder how to merge all property values of the superclass instance and my subclasses properties.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Now I'm doing this:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate {
    self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }
}
```

This way I'm able to receive the delegate methods on my subclass, extend the informations in the method and end the custom selectors to the delegate.

In the viewControllers I can do something like this:

```
mySubClass *con = [[mySubClass alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[con setDidReceiveResponseSelector:@selector(connection:didGetResponse)];
[con start];
```

So I can have like ten URLRequests within the same viewController with different delegate methods for the same action.

Answer (score 5):

Casting doesn't change an object's class. Casting just tells the compiler "This object is actually a whatever". It's for when the compiler is misunderstanding what class something is.

Given that casting doesn't seem to be working for you, then it means you're not being passed an instance of your custom subclass. So you should be looking at the code where you create the connection in the first place. I'd expect to see something like:

```
mySubClass *conn = [[mySubClass alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

Is that what your code looks like? If not (i.e. if you create an `NSURLConnection` rather than a `mySubClass`), switch to creating a `mySubClass`.

Comment: I get your point. In my subclass in the `-start` method I'm creating an instance of NSURLConnection and set the delegate to my subclass. I see that's not pretty correct. But how can I overwrite the delegate methods in my subclass? When I just implement them in my subclass, they'll never get called…

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement any of the delegate calling functionality in your subclass — it'll be inherited from the superclass.

Comment: I'd like to do something I know from ASIHTTP. There you can set the selectors of each instance (like `[con setDidFinishSelector:@selector(oneConnectionFinished:)];`). For this reason I wanted to implement the delegate to the class itself and then call the methods manually. How can I do this

Comment: Hey Amy! Thanks for your suggestions. You leaded me the right way and so I was able to solve my problem!